# image popup using html & javascript

Tags: html

i want to make image popup like the popup used in thies website on image click.
http://www.retailson.pk/productDescription.aspx?pid=43#!prettyPhoto

i want its complete css & javascript code in detail.
thanks waiting for your kind feed back.

Comment: I could also turn up a 9AM for your job. But please give me the money that from the paycheck

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow are not designed to do your work for you, but to assist with problems as you experience them. To ask a question you should show at least minimal research and understanding, and be asking for assistance with a specific problem, rather than for complete implementation of your project requirements. Remember that no-one is being paid to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Despite this question being entirely unsuitable for StackOverflow, I will offer some advice constructive to your problem (and anyone else who finds this through searching).

Image "popups" are often known as "Lightboxes" after the physical lightboxes used by artists and photographers. If you had searched for *javascript image lightbox* on your favourite search engine then you would most likely have found [Jack Moore's Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) on the first page, amongst many other fine libraries.

It is free, open source, styleable with CSS and straightforward to use. It also supports slideshows and image groups.

There is a straightforward [Beginner's Guide](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide/) which should get you started and contains the JavaScript source you were looking for. There are also full demos for most of the features of the library which contain HTML, JavaScript and CSS.